# Riley in Disguise

Tags: riddle, word

I entered, and then I took a break, but not before I started on a nice hot beverage. The whole thing made money and held people's attention.

Comment: I've edited out the "riley" tag, we [have meta consensus](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/do-prefix-suffix-infix-riddles-deserve-their-own-tag) that it doesn't need its own tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Interest

I entered

> **In**

and then I took a break

> **Rest**

but not before I started on a nice hot beverage

> **Te** both sounds like and is the start of **tea**

The whole thing made money and held people's attention.

> Double definition of **interest** here - "money paid regularly at a particular rate for the use of money lent" and "attention"